# Which WWII Medal and ribbon are these?

Tags: world-war-two, united-states, identification, army

I am trying to identify a possible medal that my great grandfather was awarded as I am putting his medals together for my grandmother. Though I'm not quite sure it's a medal. I looked through his discharge papers and still can't identify it. I attached the only image I have of it. I am specifically looking at the medal (?) on the far right. It is red, yellow, black, and white.

[image]

Additionally, he was awarded the EAME Campaign Medal with 5 bronze stars. I have looked for the 5 bronze star attachment but the highest I have found is 4. How could I go about purchasing the 5 stars?

Comment: That does not seem to be any normal US medal ribbon. Nor does the cross (second from left) look like any US medal I can find. What do you know about the dates and places where he served? Those may give clues.

Answer (score 3):

Left to right

The gold eagle is an honorable discharge lapel pin which was for wearing on the label of a civilian suit coat.  When one was discharged a similar, but cloth, patch was sewed over the right pocket to indicate that the soldier had been discharged and not subject to orders.  Very few soldiers had civilian clothes to wear home after discharge and the patch indicated to MPs and such that the individual was no longer in service but was wearing the uniform while returning home.  [Honorable Discharge Lapel Pin](https://www.medalsofamerica.com/blog/ruptured-duck-honorable-discharge-lapel-pin/)

The black cross is not a medal, it is a marksman qualification badge and worn beneath the ribbons of awarded medals.  Badges are noted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marksmanship_badges_(United_States))

Not sure what the ribbon you have is for, it does not match ribbons issued during the war that I can find, see obsolete ribbon [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awards_and_decorations_of_the_United_States_Armed_Forces#Inactive_and_obsolete_awards)

As far as devices to be worn on medals/ribbons.  If your grandfather had five awards, the ribbon itself is the first and the devices to be attached to the ribbon make up additional awards,  So, if you have four stars then, four stars plus the ribbon makes five awards.  Had he six awards, then he’d have the ribbon and a single silver star to indicate six awards.  For example, on my father’s Pacific Campaign ribbon he wore the ribbon with a silver star centered with two bronze stars on each side of the silver – 2+5+2+the ribbon = participation in 10 recognized campaigns